# Hi, I am trying to enter a data from JtextField to notepad and need old data also in same notepad

Tags: java, netbeans

.In each entering the old data is disappearing and only new data is showing there. I want both datas new and the old data. here is my code.:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
     String abc= jTextField1.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter("textFieldOutput.txt", "UTF-8");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
writer.println(abc);
writer.close();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In each entering the old data is disappearing and only new data is showing there.

Use a `FileWriter` instead of the `PrintWriter`.

Then you can open the file in "append" mode.

Read the `FileWriter` API for the appropriate constructor to use.

You will also need to use the `write(...)` method instead of the println(..) method.

Typically you would also wrap the `FileWriter` in a `BufferedWriter`. Then you can use the `newline()` method as required.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment sir .. it is worked now..